# make a controller visible with its values in appdelegate [Xcode 6]

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I am trying to transform a project that starts view a certain view that has its own ViewController and doesn't have a navigation controller to a project with a navigation controller.

The functioning project has this in the appdelegate:

```
 ViewController* viewController = (ViewController*)  self.window.rootViewController;

[viewController getBeaconInfo];
```

so when I run the code, the view controlled by the viewController gets loaded with some certain info. 
Tthe first line that I posted is now executed and if I debug it I can see that I have the correct viewController with the proper values in it. I then can call the second line successfully.

I am now transforming the project so that the first view is not the one controlled by that ViewController, but another one.
If I now run the code, when the view controlled by the ViewController gets loaded, some info are loaded there, but when the first line that I posted is executed and I debug it, I obtain a totally different object. The values in it are quite different. The

```
[viewController getBeaconInfo];
```

cannot get executed because the code has not visibility of it.
I can understand how this happens but I don't know how to solve it.
At first I tried by substituting this:

```
ViewController* viewController = (ViewController*)  self.window.rootViewController;
```

with

```
UIStoryboard *mainStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main"
                                                         bundle: nil]; 
ViewController *viewController = (ViewController *)[mainStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier: @"ViewController"];
```

but this doesn't work, because I istantiate a new object and lose completely the one with the values that I need, so when I call the method

```
[viewController getBeaconInfo];
```

I don't get what I want.

I don't know how to solve the issue.

Comment: How are you transforming the project? Are you embedding the `ViewController` in a `UINavigationViewController` in a Storyboard?

Comment: I have added some things...maybe too many.
The first controller of the project is a now a tab bar controller with tho tabs. The first tab links to a navigation controller which points to a view with a table in it. When one element of the table is clicked the user is taken to a view controller by my infamous ViewController.
I think I had tried with a simplified version of all this: starting from the functioning project (with only one view) and embed it in a navigation controller. I think the result was the same.

Comment: Ok. That sounds like a reasonable app structure. So, what are you trying to accomplish in the AppDelegate? That's really only for launching code. If you want to handle/execute something when the user selects an item and pushes `ViewController`, why don't you put that code somewhere else?

Comment: can you post the code for your new app structure?

Comment: You could create a singleton object of some kind. Instantiate it in your app delegate with the data you need, and then access it from any view controller.

Comment: I had this doubt too: why is the method called by the appdelegate and not by the viewController itself? I have now tried to call the method directly and everything seems to work. However the appdelegate is involved because of the notifications.  
So the moment I call the same method from the viewController itself and from the appdelegate. I am not sure if all this gives the desired result; I am investigating.